# Panda Table Conversion

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How can I convert the table below to a table with columns ["ID", "PC1_0.1", "PC1_0.2", "PC1_0.3", ..., "PC10_111.2"] and only 24 rows. Each row may have the same wafer ID (meaning the same wafer is used repeatedly) and data of some wafer is not recorded.
[image]

Comment: Could you please identify a specific obstacle that you are facing that could be reproduced with just a small illustrative example of a table?

Comment: Hi @DmitriChubarov I have make amendments to my post to illustrate an example, hope you can take a look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

i hope this codes work for you :)

```
d = {
     "ID":["W-01"]*4+["W-02"]*2,
     "Time":["t1","t2"]*3,
     "PC1":["00","10","20","30","40","50"],
     "PC2":["01","11","21","31","41","51"],
     }
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# for grouping on Time-PC1-PC2 and pivot
melt = df.melt(id_vars=["ID","Time"], value_vars=["PC1","PC2"])
melt["no"] = np.arange(0,melt.shape[0])
pivot = melt.pivot(index=["no","ID"], columns=["Time","variable"], values="value")

# We are combining non-nan columns because during the melt operation, nan data will emerge.
con = pd.DataFrame()
for col in range(pivot.columns.size):
    part = pivot.iloc[:,[col]].dropna()
    part = part.reset_index().drop("no", axis=1).set_index("ID")
    con = pd.concat([con, part], axis=1)
```